# Jquery color picker not working after ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, color-picker

In my site I have added a jQuery color picker textbox as like:

```
http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/
```

When loading page through ajax then this color picker is not working. That means color picker is not working after ajax call.

How can i solve this problem?

My site is a CodeIgniter site:

This is my index page source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title> Rock website</title>
<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>style/style_user_admin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>style/jquery-jvert-tabs-1.1.4.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/ajaxupload.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/colorpicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/eye.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/utils.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/layout.js?ver=1.0.2"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/colorpicker.css" type="text/css" />


<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery-jvert-tabs-1.1.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery.cleditor.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery.cleditor.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    page_setup();
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function page_setup()
    {
        $.ajax({  
                    type: "POST",  
                    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/super_admin/page_setup/",
                    success: function(msg){
                    //alert(msg);
                    $("#page_setup").html(msg).show();
                    }  
                });
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="wraper">
<div class="welcome_to_admin">
Super Admin Panel
</div>
<div class="admin_main">
<div id="vtabs1">
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#page_setup" onclick="return page_setup();">Page Setup</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div  id="page_setup">
            <!--
            load the page_setup.php page here
            -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the super_admin controller code:

```
public function page_setup()
    {
        $this->load->view('super_admin/page_setup');
    }
```

This is the page_setup.php page code:

```
<div class="tab1_rgt_part">
<div class="message_to_send_11">Color Settings</div>
  <div class="tab1_main_part" style="margin-top:20px;">
  <div class="tab1_left_part">Welcome Page Bg Color</div>
<input type="text" maxlength="6" size="6" id="colorpickerField1" value="00ff00" />
</div>
```

Comment: There isn't enough detail in the question to provide any real help! You need to post your code that a) issues the ajax call and handles its callbacks b) how and where you init your colorpicker etc.. And if possible a jsfiddle link or a link to your work

Comment: Show your **full** code. Jqery + java script + HTML

Answer (score 2):

try adding the color picker after loading the html:

```
function page_setup()
    {
        $.ajax({  
                    type: "POST",  
                    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/super_admin/page_setup/",
                    success: function(msg){
                    //alert(msg);
                    $("#page_setup").html(msg).show();
                    $("#colorpickerField1").ColorPicker(
                     onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {   
                        $(this).val(hex);
                     }
                    );
                    }  
                });
    }
```

Comment: Now color picker is displayed but i can to get the selected color to the text box 'colorpickerField1'

Comment: that is another issue that has nothing to do with ajax. make sure all the css and js files are loaded succesfully.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('#colorpickerField1, #colorpickerField2, #colorpickerField3,#colorpickerField4).ColorPicker({
    onSubmit: function(hsb, hex, rgb, el) {
        $(el).val("#"+hex);
        //$(el).css("background-color","#"+hex);
        $(el).ColorPickerHide();
    },
    onBeforeShow: function () {
        $(this).ColorPickerSetColor(this.value);
    }
})
```

I found the answer.Add this code in a script tag at the top of the view page